# Replace characters and wrap them in a tag, using one regular expression

Tags: python, regex

I want to convert the strings:

- `CPP` to `C<sup>++</sup>`
- `CP` to `C<sup>+</sup>`
- `C` to `C`.

Currently I do this using two regular expressions:

```
mystring = "CPP"

a = re.sub(r"P", "+", mystring)
b = re.sub(r"(\++)", r"<sup>\1</sup>", a)

print b # C<sup>++</sup>
```

This works; but I would like to do this using one regular expression. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a similar solution:

```
import re
s = "CPP" # to C<sup>++</sup>
rx = r"(?<=\bC)P+\b"
res = re.sub(rx, (lambda m: "<sup>%s</sup>"%("+" * len(m.group(0)))), s)
print(res)
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/YzjCJL)

The regex `(?<=\bC)P+\b` matches a word beginning with `C` and ending in any number of `P`s. The `"+" * len(m.group(0))` allows replacement of any number of `P`s with `+`s.

Answer (score 2):

It would be possible through `re.sub` by using an anonymous function in the replacement part.

```
>>> def change(s):
    return re.sub(r'\b(C)(P{1,2})\b', lambda m: m.group(1) + ('<sup>++</sup>' if len(m.group(2)) == 2 else  '<sup>+</sup>'), s)

>>> print(change('CPP'))
C<sup>++</sup>
>>> print(change('CP'))
C<sup>+</sup>
>>> print(change('CP'))
C<sup>+</sup>
>>> print(change('C'))
C
```

Comment: arguably, this might not be a nicer solution the the OPs. just because it's a one liner, doesnt mean its better

Comment: Ok, just write a better solution than this.

Comment: i was saying, that it might not be a nicer solution to do it in one line